# How react-router works on generating the routes from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-framework

So basically how react-router works on generating the routes from an array? I have been building this recipe app but generating routes is what got me stuck. From some reason the routes dont get created so when I click on the recipe Link, it redirects me to blank page without displaying the content.

[Full github code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/ackee)

App.js

```
import RecipeList from './RecipeList';
import './App.css';
import RecipeProvider from './RecipeContext'
import Form from './Form';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import Details from './Details';

function App() {

  const [recipes,setRecipes]=useContext(RecipeContext) 
  
  return (


<RecipeProvider>

<Router>
<Switch>
  

<>
<Route exact path="/">
<RecipeList/>
</Route>
<Route exact path="/pridat-recept">
<Form/>
</Route>

{recipes.map(item=>(
  
<Route exact path={`/${item.name}`} >
<Details key={item.name}/>
</Route>

)

)}



</>
</Switch>
</Router>

</RecipeProvider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Recipe.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from "./vitaminDfood-1132105308-770x553.jpg"
import './Recipe.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Details from './Details';
function Recipe(props) {
    return (
        <div className="recipe">
        <div className="first-column">
        <img src={Image} alt="cam"/>
        </div>
        <div className="second-column">
     <Link to={`/${props.name}`}><p className="name">{props.name}</p></Link> 
       <p> {props.score.toFixed(2)}</p>
       <p className="time"><i className="far fa-clock"></i>{props.duration}<span>min.</span></p> 
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recipe
```

Details.js

```
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import './Details.css'
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function Details() {

  return (
    <h1>hry</h1>
    )
}

export default Details;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you could use the map() method to render every item or object in the array. After when you render you can put  which will generate you to the link from the array id.

That is the option you can put react-router from an array by using the id's.

Comment: I don't understand, I am already using the map method, can you explain more?